# Ant XSLT task to build on mutiple dependencies

Tags: ant, xslt

I have an XSL style sheet that merges external documents, this way
`<xsl:copy-of select="document('snippets.xml')/snippets/xxxx/form"/>`

I would like that the XSLT Ant build task rebuilds if the file or any of its dependencies changed.

The current Ant task looks like this

`<xslt  basedir="xxxx/pages/${doc.locale}"

    destdir="xxxx/dir/${doc.locale}"

includes="*.xml"

excludes="snippets.xml"

style="build/xxxx/${doc.locale}/myStyle.xsl">

             <param name="lang" expression="${doc.locale}"/>

             <xmlcatalog refid="docDTDs"/>`

Basically I would like to rebuild if the snippets.xml document is changed.

Comment: Have a look at the `uptodate` task for setting a property that your xslt task can check against.  It is not clear what the exact dependencies are from your question, but `uptodate` is the Ant task to use when wanting to conditionalize processing based on file timestamps.

Comment: My file depends on snippets.xml. Can u elaborate a bit on `uptodate` usage, because I have a hardtime understand how to use it. I'm no Ant expert.

Comment: I posted an answer providing an example of `uptodate`.  It may not be complete since I'm still not clear on what the file dependencies may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant has the `uptodate` task to check if a target is up-to-date, file modtime-wise, from a set of source files.  I'm not completely clear on what your dependency is since the XSLT task could create multiple files (resulting in multiple targets), or if it creates a single file.  One of your comments imply a single file.

The following is one way to use `uptodate`.  You basically use the task to set a property that can then be put in the `unless` attribute of a target:

```
<property name="file.that.depends.on.snippets"
          location="some/path"/>
<property name="snippets.file"
          location="xxxx/pages/${doc.locale}/snippets.xml"/>

<target name="process-snippets"
        unless="snippets.uptodate"
        depends="snippets-uptodate-check">
  <xslt basedir="xxxx/pages/${doc.locale}"
        destdir="xxxx/dir/${doc.locale}"
        includes="*.xml"
        excludes="snippets.xml"
        style="build/xxxx/${doc.locale}/myStyle.xsl">
    <param name="lang" expression="${doc.locale}"/>
    <xmlcatalog refid="docDTDs"/>
  </xslt>
</target>

<target name="snippets-uptodate-check">
  <uptodate property="snippets.uptodate"
            targetfile="$file.that.depends.on.snippets">
    <srcfiles dir="xxxx/pages/${doc.locale}"
              includes="*.xml"
              excludes="snippets.xml"/>

  </uptodate>
</target>
```

Comment: Got it working for a single file in the xslt basedir. I need to apply this for all `*.xml` in that directory. So I need to work around the implicit fileset of the `<xslt>`

Answer (score -1):

The [XSLT task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) should do this for you by default. It has an optional "force" attribute

> Recreate target files, even if they
>   are newer than their corresponding
>   source files or the stylesheet

which is false by default. So by default, unless you override with the "force" attribute, dependencies are checked by the XSLT task.

Comment: The issue is that the XSLT uses the `document()` function, and the ANT `<xslt>` task doesn't know to look at the dynamically loaded resources in order to determine whether it should execute. You could use `@force`, but then would unnecessarily be generating output if none of the resource files had changed.

Comment: not answering the question at all, since it means not checking anything.

Comment: @millebii, I think you missed my point. I was not suggesting that you should use the "force" attribute, which indeed means not checking anything. What I was pointing out was that the default behaviour was the opposite - that dependencies are checked by default. But I see that in your case this behaviour is defeated by the use of document() function.